# In SQLite, how do I alter a table to add a column with default null and foreign key constraint?

Tags: sqlite

The SQLite doc says:

> It is not possible to use the "ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN" syntax to
>   add a column that includes a REFERENCES clause, unless the default
>   value of the new column is NULL.

I can't get my `ALTER TABLE` statement to work, it looks like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Customers ADD COLUMN AddressID INTEGER DEFAULT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES MasterAddress (AddressID);
```

I can see references to workarounds that create a constraint at `CREATE TABLE` time and bouncing the data through a new table but I would prefer altering my existing table.  Is this possible?

I have set `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DEFAULT NULL` is the default; you do not need to specifiy it.

`FOREIGN KEY` is used to introduce a table constraint, but ALTER TABLE supports only column constraints. The syntax for a column constraint does not have the `FOREIGN KEY`:

```
ALTER TABLE Customers ADD AddressID INTEGER REFERENCES MasterAddress(AddressID);
```

Comment: Thanks, that gets me going.